# In convex optimization we know that the optimum solution is on which hyper plane

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-optimization, linear-programming, convex-analysis

We have a standard linear program, I mean a set of inequalities $c_i^Tx\leq b_i$ where $i\in \{1,\ldots ,k\}$ and we want to find $max\{c^Ty| y\in \{\cap \{x|c_i^Tx\leq b_i\}\}$. I put some condition on this set of inequalities and after that I found a special $i$ such that the optimum solution is on hyper plane $c_i^Tx=b_i$.

Do you think it is useful or I can extend this? Or there is some reference in which I can find some thing about this?

Comment: linear programming is contained in conic programming. I am not sure what you are look after.